# Formatting 2 columns in a list box. 1 is number, the other text

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I need to create a list box which is showing 2 columns.  The first is a numerical status and the next is the description.  The status can be up to 3 integers.

What I want to get is the status to be right-aligned, followed by a space and then the description.

In effect

```
Code Description
  1  Descrition for code 1
 10  Descrition for code 10
100  Descrition for code 100
```

My code so far:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "prc_GetData";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("piCompany", OracleDbType.Char, "01", ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.Connection = con;

OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

con.Open();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(dt);

DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("NewCol");
dc.Expression = string.Format("{0}+' '+{1}", "NumberCol", "TextCol");
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

ListBox1.DataSource = dt;
ListBox1.DataValueField = "NumberCol";
//  ListBox1.DataTextField = (String.Format("{0} {1}", "NumberCol", "TextCol"));
ListBox1.DataTextField = ("NewCol");
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: If you can change the procedure "prc_GetData", you can select NumberCol[Space]TextCol from your stored procedure and bind that column to DataTextField.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a gridview to perform it: in this way you have a table structure. You can also look at `DataList` control.

You can also write your control overriding `ListBox` and editing the `RenderControl()` method but it's more difficult.

In alternative you can use a jquery plugin. You can find different types for a multicolumns listbox as:

http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/multi-column

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by:

```
using (con)
 {
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.CommandText = "prc_GetData";
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("piCompany", OracleDbType.Char, "01", ParameterDirection.Input));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("poRecordset", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output));
   cmd.Connection = con;

   OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   con.Open();
   da.SelectCommand = cmd;
   da.Fill(dt);

   dt.Columns.Add("FORMAT_COL", typeof(String));

   string space = "&nbsp;";
   space = Server.HtmlDecode(space);

   foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
   {
       dr["FORMAT_COL"] = dr["NumberCol"].ToString().PadLeft(5, Convert.ToChar(space));
   }
   dt.Columns.Add("COMB_COL", typeof(String));
   dt.Columns["COMB_COL"].Expression = "FORMAT_COL + '  (' + TextCol + ')'";

   ListBox1.DataSource = dt;
   ListBox1.DataValueField = "NumberCol";
   ListBox1.DataTextField = "COMB_COL";

   ListBox1.DataBind();
 }
```